# import classes with Swift iOS

Tags: swift

I'm trying Swift and I'm having some troubles..
I have a TableViewController.swift and also a DataModel.swift but I don't know how to import DataModel class into TableViewController to use in it. I'm trying with

```
import DPBDataModel.swift
```

but it doesn't works (No such module)

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: You don't need to import anything except frameworks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try just using your `DataModel` class into `TableViewController` without importing anything ;-)

Comment: Woow!! It works!. it's most simple than Obj-c :) Thanks Zedenem

Comment: Hi @macdonjo, can you give us more details on what's wrong so we can help?

Comment: So i have two .swift files in my playground folder, one of them defines 'myClass', can i just use it in the other file without importing anything? I see the same error as the second guy who commented

Answer (score 7):

We need not to import any class in swift like objective c
Simply instantiate your class & you can use it.